# Algorithm for calculating duration between Night-Morning

Tags: java, algorithm, time, java-time, duration

I'm stuck in a Duration calculation problem given in my College Assignment. So, the user get to enter a Starting time and an Ending time, where hours and minutes are entered separately to the program. Hours are entered in 24h format(00 - 23). My program successfully calculate durations where 'Ending time' is greater than 'Starting time', with a simple 'Ending time - Starting time'. Eg: 23.55 - 22.55 = 1h. But my problem appears when something like this happens, 'Starting time = 23.45' and 'Ending time = 00.45'. So  the earlier method wont work for this.

So I need a little help with this, since I'm still learning the basics of **Java** and this is a College assignment I cant do anything outside the lessons(Complex stuff). So I'd prefer to stay in the basics(BODMAS) and do it. Please ask if more information is needed!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What have you done till now? Add existing code in your question.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812) for the StackOverflow policy on homework.  You really need to show some effort, and some existing code, especially if you're asking for homework help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
if (start_time > end_time) end_time += 24 hours
duration = end_time - start_time
```

Or more succinctly

```
duration = end_time + (end_time < startTime ? 24 : 0) - start_time
```

The changes necessary to distinguish whether `end_time == start_time` means zero or 24 hours are left as an exercise.

Comment: OMG, This is so simple, why didnt I thought of this! I've been trying with 10 lines of Algorithm still doesnt work, and this is only 1 line! LoL. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

### *java.time*

I recommend you use the `java.time` API to do it. The steps can be summarized in the following points:

1. Create the instances of `LocalDateTime` using the current date at start time and the end time.
2. If the `LocalDateTime` instance for end time is before the one for the start time, reset the instance for the end time to the midnight, then add one day to it and finally apply the time to it.
3. Use `java.time.Duration` to get the duration between the instances of the `LocalDateTime`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the start hour: ");
        int startHour = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the start minute: ");
        int startMinute = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the start hour: ");
        int endHour = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the start minute: ");
        int endMinute = scanner.nextInt();

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

        LocalDateTime startDateTime = date.atTime(LocalTime.of(startHour, startMinute));
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = date.atTime(LocalTime.of(endHour, endMinute));

        if (startDateTime.isAfter(endDateTime)) {
            endDateTime = endDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIN).plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.of(endHour, endMinute));
        }

        Duration duration = Duration.between(startDateTime, endDateTime);

        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        System.out.println(
                "Total duration: " + String.format("%02d:%02d", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutes() % 60));
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        System.out.println(
                "Total duration: " + String.format("%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart()));
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the start hour: 23
Enter the start minute: 45
Enter the start hour: 0
Enter the start minute: 45
PT1H
Total duration: 01:00
Total duration: 01:00
```

[`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

Learn more about ***java.time*** API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).